# I want to get some letters using the Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, numbers

As I said on the title, I want to get some letters using 'Regular Expressions'. But I don't know how to get it.

`re.findall("\d*\.?\d+[^Successful 50/50s]", a)`

'Defence\nClean sheets\n53\nGoals conceded\n118\nTackles\n186\nTackle success %\n75%\nLast man tackles\n2\nBlocked shots\n24\nInterceptions\n151\nClearances\n805\nHeaded Clearance\n380\nClearances off line\n3\nRecoveries\n666\nDuels won\n435\nDuels lost\n330\nSuccessful 50/50s\n25\nAerial battles won\n206\nAerial battles lost\n193\nOwn goals\n1\nErrors leading to goal\n1Team Play\nAssists\n2\nPasses\n7,979\nPasses per match\n56.19\nBig chances created\n3\nCrosses\n48\nCross accuracy %\n25%\nThrough balls\n10\nAccurate long balls\n936Discipline\nYellow cards\n13\nRed cards\n0\nFouls\n48\nOffsides\n2Attack\nGoals\n6\nHeaded goals\n4\nGoals with right foot\n1\nGoals with left foot\n1\nHit woodwork\n3'

**I want to get just the number including floats and % but excepting the 'Successful 50/50s'. But also want to remain thousand’s place like 7,979.**

Comment: Can you share your current effort/regex. And what's the expected output from above text?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi
I just find this re.findall("\d*\.?\d+[^Successful 50/50s]", a). But, I wanna get all number and thousand’s place like 7,979. And want to remove 'Successful 50/50s'

Comment: Ok got it, you want to match all numbers except those `50/50` right? And you want the numbers matched with `,` between them as well.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi
Yes, that's it :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will match all numbers except the one where your numbers are preceded and followed by a slash like `50/50`

```
(?<!/)\d*(?:,\d+)*\.?\d+\b(?!/)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG4J6w/1/)**

Your updated Python code,

```
import re

s = '''Defence\nClean sheets\n53\nGoals conceded\n118\nTackles\n186\nTackle success %\n75%\nLast man tackles\n2\nBlocked shots\n24\nInterceptions\n151\nClearances\n805\nHeaded Clearance\n380\nClearances off line\n3\nRecoveries\n666\nDuels won\n435\nDuels lost\n330\nSuccessful 50/50s\n25\nAerial battles won\n206\nAerial battles lost\n193\nOwn goals\n1\nErrors leading to goal\n1',
 'Team Play\nAssists\n2\nPasses\n7,979\nPasses per match\n56.19\nBig chances created\n3\nCrosses\n48\nCross accuracy %\n25%\nThrough balls\n10\nAccurate long balls\n936',
 'Discipline\nYellow cards\n13\nRed cards\n0\nFouls\n48\nOffsides\n2',
 'Attack\nGoals\n6\nHeaded goals\n4\nGoals with right foot\n1\nGoals with left foot\n1\nHit woodwork\n3'''

print(re.findall(r'(?<!/)\d*(?:,\d+)*\.?\d+\b(?!/)', s))
```

Prints all numbers except those `50`/`50`,

```
['53', '118', '186', '75', '2', '24', '151', '805', '380', '3', '666', '435', '330', '25', '206', '193', '1', '1', '2', '7,979', '56.19', '3', '48', '25', '10', '936', '13', '0', '48', '2', '6', '4', '1', '1', '3']
```

Comment: Thank u :) Rajwanshi !! I checked your code. And it worked well.
But I gave you wrong code previous question.

Comment: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42408554/57843469-505fb880-7809-11e9-82a3-20455b18f9ea.png)

Comment: @YoungdongKim: It is not clear as what numbers exactly you want to match. Can you add the numbers that you want in the output?

Comment: @Rajwanshi
53, 118, 186, 75, 2, 24, 151, 805, 380, 3, 666, 435, 330, 25, 206, 193, 1, 1, 2, 7979, 56.19, 3, 48, 25, 10, 936, 13, 0, 48, 2, 6, 4, 1, 1, 3

These number what I want to get. Thank you!

Comment: @Rajwanshi
I solved the problems using your suggestion!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @YoungdongKim: The only difference I saw was, you wanted to remove the comma from one of the digit, for which you will have to remove the comma as a secondary step from the number as using just match you can't get two disjointed text as one.